# How to read Image from Oracle (long raw format) in GoLang

Tags: oracle, go, long-integer

I am trying to read images (in long raw datatype) from external Oracle database using Golang code.

When sql's row.Next() is called following error is caught:
ORA-01406: fetched column value was truncated

row.Next works fine for reading blob images from mssql DB.

Example code:

```
db, err := sql.Open("oci8", getDSN()) //function to get connection details 
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT image FROM sysadm.all_images")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    for rows.Next() {
       var id string
       var data []byte
       rows.Scan(&id, &data)    
    }
    fmt.Println("Total errors", rows.Err())
}
```

I hope someone can help me to fix this issue or pinpoint to problem area.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using `go-oci8` as the driver.

Based on this issue https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/pull/71 there are someone who get the same error like yours, and then managed to fix it by modifying some codes on the driver.

As per this [commit](https://github.com/mattn/go-oci8/commit/5e46694007e7f07045681911ef71634dd5bee8a9), the problem is already solved by increasing the value of `oci8cols[i].size` on file `$GOPATH/src/github.com/mattn/go-oci8/oci8.go`. I think in your case you have bigger blob data, that's why the revision is still not working.

```
case C.SQLT_NUM:
    oci8cols[i].kind = C.SQLT_CHR
    oci8cols[i].size = int(lp * 4) // <==== THIS VALUE
    oci8cols[i].pbuf = C.malloc(C.size_t(oci8cols[i].size) + 1)
```

So, try to increase the multiplier, like:

```
oci8cols[i].size = int(lp * 12) // <==== OR GREATER
```

Comment: Thanks for comment @nvl. You are right I am using mattn oracle package. Looks like currently this package does not support long raw. i really wonder if anyone happened to solve this problem before :(

Comment: try to change code `oci8cols[i].size = int(lp * 12)` on `oci8.pc`, some one able to get rid this error by changing that

Comment: basically just increase the buffer, `lp * 12` or greater

Comment: thanks for your feedback. It gets too heavy for package to load. + few images are not loaded properly. They get downloaded half way.